# Combining Filtering and string concatenation with DRY

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, refactoring

Consider this code:

```
var marketing = marketingRepository.Suggestions(selectedID, sourceTypeID, providerID);

SomeObject sObj = new SomeObject();

SomeObject.StudentIds = string.Join(",", marketing.Where(p => p.TypeID == 43)
                 .Select(p => p.MappingID.ToString()));

supplierMarketingObject.TeacherIds = string.Join(",", marketing.Where(p => p.TypeID == 44)
                .Select(p => p.MappingID.ToString()));

supplierMarketingObject.OtherIds = string.Join(",", marketing.Where(p => p.TypeID == 45)
               .Select(p => p.MappingID.ToString()));
```

Marketing list is filtered based on the TypeId and assigned to the respective collections.
As there is a lot of repeated code, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define local lambda with common operations:

```
Func<int, string> getMappingIdsByTypeId =
    typeId => string.Join(",", marketing.Where(p => p.TypeID == typeId)
                                        .Select(p => p.MappingID.ToString()));

sObj.StudentIds = getMappingIdsByTypeId(43);
supplierMarketingObject.TeacherIds = getMappingIdsByTypeId(44);
supplierMarketingObject.OtherIds = getMappingIdsByTypeId(45);
```